# Proving triangulizability using the primary decomposition theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was just wondering whether I could prove the following thing

> If $T$ is a linear operator whose minimal polynomial is of the form :$(x-c_1)^{r_1}....(x-c_k)^{r_k}$.Then can I use the primary decomposition theorem to prove that $T$ is triangular linear operator.

If yes, then how do I proceed?Can someone give me hints ,without giving the whole proof.

Comment: The primary decomposition theorem allows us to concentrate on each generalised eigenspace $N(T-c_i)^{r_i}$. The usual proof is then to use induction on their dimension, starting with an eigenvector.